# No funciona arraylist en otra clase

Tags: arraylist, clase

mi problema es, que los datos de mi arraylist se borran al usarlo en otra clase, tengo el crud agregar y consultar obras en una clase, y funcionan ambas creo y consulto y todo bien, pero cuando restauro obra en una clase aparte, y recorro el arraylist no funciona no existen objetos, que se le debe agregar para que funcione ? herencia o algo por el estilo? , sorry soy novato recien aprendiendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta en otra clase y el arraylist no funciona 
[image]

Comment: Nota: esto no es instagram! es stackoverflow por favor edita tu pregunta y coloca codigo en vez de imagenes! o sera marcada como de muy baja calidad o cerrada!

Comment: Es un error de concepto muy simple. Pero sin codigo en texto ....